# How do I "reworker" in buildbot (or, how to fix the missing force button)?

Tags: buildbot

Starting with this buildbot master config:

```
# -*- python -*-
# ex: set filetype=python:

from buildbot.plugins import *

c = BuildmasterConfig = {}
c['workers'] = [worker.Worker("example-worker", "pass")]
c['protocols'] = {'pb': {'port': 9989}}
c['change_source'] = []
c['schedulers'] = []
c['schedulers'].append(schedulers.ForceScheduler(
                            name="force",
                            builderNames=["awesomesauce", "runtests"]))

factory = util.BuildFactory()
factory.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(command=['echo', 'hi']))

c['builders'] = []
c['builders'].append(
    util.BuilderConfig(name="runtests",
      workernames=["example-worker"],
      factory=factory))

c['builders'].append(
    util.BuilderConfig(name="awesomesauce",
      workernames=["example-worker"],
      factory=factory))

c['status'] = []
c['title'] = "Cool Beans"
c['titleURL'] = "http://example.com"
c['buildbotURL'] = "http://localhost:8010/"
c['www'] = dict(port=8010,
                plugins=dict(waterfall_view={}, console_view={}))
c['db'] = {
    'db_url' : "sqlite:///state.sqlite",
}
```

If I change the `ForceScheduler` to have the following:

```
builderNames=['awesomesauce', 'runtests', 'coolbeans']
```

And then simply copy the builders append block and change the name:

```
c['builders'].append(
    util.BuilderConfig(name="coolbeans",
      workernames=["example-worker"],
      factory=factory))
```

Then when I do:

```
buildbot reconfigure master
```

It says that it added new builders, however when I go to the builders page it only lists the worker for for my original two builders, and the `force` button is missing from the builder page. Ruh roh.

Is there a way to fix the worker/builder link without completely restarting my buildbot master?

Answer (score 1):

For the Force button, I'd say you have to also reconfigure the ForceScheduler, which is not part of your description.

For the worker assignment it looks like indeed this is a bug of our reconfiguration algorithm
http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/3629#ticket

This bug only affects the UI. The builder is still configured with this worker, and should be able to start builds with that worker

Comment: It's buried right underneath the config file - `If I change the ForceScheduler...` - I'm definitely changing the scheduler. That bug might be applicable, though from the description I'm not entirely sure :P